# Angular ngFor individual item events

Tags: jquery, asp.net, angular, typescript

TypeScript:

```
showText: boolean = false;

  hoverStateIn(){
    this.showText = true
  }

  hoverStateOut(){
    this.showText = false;
  }
```

Html

```
<ul> 
<li class="txt-block"
    *ngFor='let fruit of fruitsToDisplay;let i = index'>
  <div class="form-control">
      <input type='text' (mouseenter)="hoverStateIn()" (mouseleave)="hoverStateOut()" id = 'frt'+i name='fruit'/>
      <span *ngIf = 'showText'> {{fruit}} </span>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Here we are getting the textboxes dynamically using the ngFor. When ever mouseenter happens in the textbox, I want to show corresponding Span element.

But whenever, I am entering mouse in to a specific text box, all the span elements are showing. Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: You will need a `showText` property per `fruit`, either as a property on the `fruit` object, or in a separate array

Comment: @user184994 Any demo would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thcrnk

Comment: @Pearl Demo using a directive. might be helpful to you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-append-and-remove-element-using-directive

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this using CSS, which may be simpler. It also reduces the need to maintain the `hover` state in your TS code, so you can remove the `(mouseenter)` and `(mouseleave)` bindings.

By default, set it to `display: none`:

```
input + span {
  display: none;
}
```

When the `input` is in a `hover` state, then display the span

```
input:hover + span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

You may want to give the `span` a useful class name to use instead of just using `span` in the CSS rule, but that's up to you

**[Here is a demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s9t7qq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to use index for showText

```
 showText: any = [];

  hoverStateIn(index){
    this.showText[index] = true;
  }

  hoverStateOut(index){
    this.showText[index] = false;
  }

<ul> 
<li class="txt-block"
    *ngFor='let fruit of fruitsToDisplay;let i = index'>
  <div class="form-control">
      <input type='text' (mouseenter)="hoverStateIn(i)" (mouseleave)="hoverStateOut(i)" id = 'frt'+i name='fruit'/>
      <span *ngIf = 'showText[i]'> {{fruit}} </span>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Here is the stackblitz code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yh1cd4

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have no binding between your mouseenter handler and the span that you need to show, this needs to be a one to one relationship, whereas in your case, it is a one to many relationship. Changing your code to fix this issue would look like:

```js
showText: Array<boolean> = this.fruitsToDisplay.map(value => false);

  hoverStateIn(index){
    this.showText[index] = true
  }

  hoverStateOut(index){
    this.showText[index] = false;
  }
```

```html
<ul> 
<li class="txt-block"
    *ngFor='let fruit of fruitsToDisplay;let i = index'>
  <div class="form-control">
      <input type='text' (mouseenter)="hoverStateIn(i)" (mouseleave)="hoverStateOut(i)" id = 'frt'+i name='fruit'/>
      <span *ngIf = 'showText[i]'> {{fruit}} </span>
    </li>
 </ul>
```